# How to identify a keyboard from HID when is attached via USB on Linux

Tags: python, hid

I have a problem to identify what kind of device has been attached via USB, I am developing with Python and I am using a watcher to check any changes on the folder /dev/input.
As soon as I attach a device, I get an alert that something has changed, but I need to hook up the new device with the library evdev.
In this point I am not sure how can I check if the device is genuine keyboard or barcode scanner instead of a mouse or other devices.

Does every keyboard has a "keyboard" word into the description? Does the HID using a special driver only for keyboard and another one for mouse?

The keyboard that I am going to attach is not going to be a unique one, I can go to the shop a buy a new one and then it should work when it's plugged.

I am not 100% sure how the HID and Plug&Play works on Linux, so I need to get some more information about them.

Summary:
- Code: Python
- Library: evdev

- Goal: hook up the keyboard/barcode scanner just plugged with a python script using the evdev library